# Refresh timer c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, timer, refresh

Hy, i need to refresh timer value to 0 every time i press Start button. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
    namespace Timer
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            int counter = 0;
            bool counting = true;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timer.Interval = 1000;
            }

            private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (timer.Enabled)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    btnStart.Text = "START";
                    lbTime.Items.Add("Time:" + lbCounter.Text);
                    lbCounter.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    btnStart.Text = "STOP";
                }
            }

            private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Count();
            }

            private void Count()
            {
                counter++;
                lbCounter.Text = counter.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

When i press Start button timer starts counting from 0. When i press it again it stops. And the third time it should start from 0 again but it continues from where it stopped last time it counted.

Comment: Is this a serious question? Set `counter = 0 ;`

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your counter to 0 when you stop the timer:

```
   private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            btnStart.Text = "START";
            lbTime.Items.Add("Time:" + lbCounter.Text);
            counter = 0;
            lbCounter.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Start();
            btnStart.Text = "STOP";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (timer.Enabled)
           {
                timer.Stop();
                btnStart.Text = "START";
                lbTime.Items.Add("Time:" + lbCounter.Text);
                lbCounter.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                counter = 0; // Added code.
                timer.Start();
                btnStart.Text = "STOP";
            }
```